# How to dereference void* in ctypes?

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

Consider the following code:

```
import ctypes

IPC_PRIVATE, MAP_SIZE, IPC_CREAT, IPC_EXCL = 0, 65536, 512, 1024

shmget = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6").shmget
shmat = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6").shmat

shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, MAP_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0600)
trace_bits = shmat(shm_id, 0, 0)
s = ctypes.string_at(ctypes.c_void_p(trace_bits), 1)
print(s[0])
```

When I try to run it, it gives me a "segmentation fault" after a successful run of `shmat`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are Python bindings for SysV shm already. How come you're not using one of those?

Comment: I'd rather avoid adding extra dependencies for two ctypes calls. Also, I'd like to learn how to solve the problem I described in the question.

Comment: Set `shmat.restype = ctypes.c_void_p`. Or better, set it to a `c_char` array pointer and dereference it to get the mapped shared memory as a ctypes array, e.g. `shmat.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char * MAP_SIZE)`. Then use `trace_array = shmat(shm_id, None, 0)[0]`.

Comment: @eryksun: thanks, that solved it for me! Feel invited to post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Do you know if your constants `IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_CREAT, IPC_EXCL` are cross-platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all `ctypes` functions which are wrapped like this have `restype == c_int`. So you need to set it correctly before you call it. The same is for `argtypes`.